# Run redis-server as PyCharm configuration

Tags: redis, pycharm

Every time I start one of my PyCharm projects, I have to go into a terminal window and start redis with the command `redis-server`. How can I add this as a run/debug configuration so I can combine it with other parts of my app? My goal is to have a single compound configuration that starts a Django web server, background worker, and redis.

Answer (score 2):

In the run\debug configuration menu you can add shell script. But Redis process only possible to stop with ctrl+c.

[image]